# while loop not working?

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement

Can someone find why this loop isn't working?  I'm new to C#.

```
while (move == "r" || move == "s" || move == "f")
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter your move: ");
                move = Console.ReadLine();


                switch (move)
                {
                    case "r":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have reloaded, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have shielded, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have fired, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("\nInvalid move, try again\n\n");
                        break;
                }


            }
```

Comment: "Not working" meaning what ? It doesn't go in the loop ? it doesn't stop ? it quits prematurely ? Have you tried to debug and see what's the actual value of move ?

Comment: It doesn't loop, but Rasel's answer worked very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because move is initialized inside the loop and is probably null or an empty string since I can't see the code before the loop I'm assuming its not initialized.

My suggestion is to use a boolean flag that is set as such

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    // do work
    if (move == finalMove) // or whatever your finish condition is
        done = true; // you could also put this as a case inside your switch
}
```

Comment: Not only move may not be initialized but assuming it is; if the user enters something different from r,s or f, the while loop will end also. If you want to keep in the loop, handle the default case by setting move to one of the values you expect in the condition.

Comment: I think that may be some of the logic because if the person enters an invalid move he may want it to just stop instead of reporting an error.

Comment: if that's intended why does he show: "Invalid move, try again" instead of "Oh, you are an idiot, good bye!"? He should add a "q" option and exit the loop on "q" or something like that.

Comment: I messed upon my code sorry, on invalid move i acutally want to loop to continue, i meant the == to be !=

Answer (score 1):

Jesus is right, suggest you accept his answer.  Here's how you can rewrite the code.

```
do
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter your move: ");
                move = Console.ReadLine();


                switch (move)
                {
                    case "r":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have reloaded, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have shielded, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        Console.Write("\nYou have fired, press enter for Genius");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("\nInvalid move, try again\n\n");
                        break;
                }


            }
 while (move == "r" || move == "s" || move == "f");
```

Note however that if you get something besides "r", "s", or "f" you will print `Invalid move, try again` and then exit your loop (they can't try again).  You might instead want to assign a key (maybe "q" for quit) that does terminate the loop and change your `while` condition to something like

```
while (move != "q");
```

Comment: Oh, I meant it the other way around, so invalid move initiates loop.  I'll just change == to !=, thanks